# How to convert image to [1,0,0,1,0] pixel array with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, image, opencv, pixel

I've been trying to solve this Python problem for the last 4 days...
I have a black and white image (.png or .jpg), for example:
[image: image example]

I would like to load it (let's call it "heart.png") and convert it to the following array format:

```
[1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1],
[0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1],
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
[1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],
```

In words: I would like to analyse every single pixel in every row and convert it to a matrix that writes white as "1" and black as "0" (or the other way around..doesn't matter, because I can invert colours before), divided by comma between pixels, every row should be hold in square brackets and also divided by comma.

I really need help with this, I think OpenCV could solve this but I don't know how...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by a "row", or a "pixel"? Is the image actually as you show, or is that a deliberately zoomed-in version intended to show the individual pixels of the image? Reading an image and getting all of the *actual* pixel data is trivial (and you [should be able to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) figure it out by [looking it up](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+read+image+into+array)). If the task is to *recognize* fake "pixels" in an artificially blown-up image, that is considerably more difficult.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel
Thank you for your answer! But that is not exactly what I wanted, "1" and "0" are not divided by comma...there is a space between them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use OpenCV and Numpy to read the image, assuming your image is grayscale with just black and white colors.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("your-image-here.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # The image pixels have range [0, 255]
img //= 255  # Now the pixels have range [0, 1]
img_list = img.tolist() # We have a list of lists of pixels

result = ""
for row in img_list:
    row_str = [str(p) for p in row]
    result += "[" + ", ".join(row_str) + "],\n"
```

If your image is more complicated than what you posted in your question then you should probably use more advanced techniques such as thresholding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But that is not exactly what I wanted, "1" and "0" are not divided by comma...there is a space between them

Comment: I got the solution by myself, you first have to convert it to list as you said and then use print(repr(list))

Comment: Oops, I edited the response to add the missing part.